# What should be azurerm_image.source_virtual_machine_id to spun linux vm on azure using terraform script?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-managed-disk

We have created custom OS image -- managed disk 
and need to spun a VM using terraform script
to use the custom created images
we need to either specifiy the publisher,owner,version,sku or the image id

if we go and check in the Azure Portal -> Image -> "Overview" -> .....
the space for blob uri ---- blank
and using the Resource ID in terraform script is not helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check example in the [document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html)(Example Usage with Managed Disks and Custom Images (Recommended)).

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "test" {
  name                  = "acctvm"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.test.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    id="${data.azurerm_image.image.id}"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
```

Note: The id is your managed disk resource ID not blob URL.

[image]